# vba select offset cell after selecting target? Not working?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo Errormask

    With Target
        If .Column = 30 And .Row > 16 And .Value = "Remove" Then
            .EntireRow.Delete
            Target.Offset(, 2).Select
        End If
    End With

Errormask:
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Exit Sub

End Sub
```

If a user clicks on the cell in column 30 which contains "remove", it should delete the row and then select the cell 1 across.

This is not working. Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: what is "cell 1 across" ? you mean 1 cell to the left ? right? tob? down? diagonal ?

Comment: You are already in a `With` so remove `Target` from `Target.Offset(, 2).Select` for a start.

Comment: @TimWilkinson thanks it still doesn't work though with or without the Target

Comment: _This is not working. Please can someone show me where I am going wrong?_ The first thing you are doing wrong is asking a vague question. We don't have your screen in front of you, we don't know what you expect to happen, and we have no idea in what way the program is defeating those expectations. You say the program is supposed to do two things: 1) delete a row, and 2) select another cell. Does the program delete any row? the wrong row? Is any cell selected? Is the wrong cell selected?

Comment: Have you performed basic debugging steps, like setting a breakpoint and following the code along with the debugger? Maybe the code is falling on some side error and going to the error handler? Do you understand what all the parts of this code do, or did you just copy/paste it from some random corner of the Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `with`, do the offset on the line below before deleting the entire row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
With Target
If Target.CurrentRegion.Count = 1 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If .Column = 30 And .Row > 16 And .Value Like "Remove" Then
        .Offset(1, 2).Select
        .EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End If
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

Are you sure you have this in the code of your sheet and not in a module?

**EDIT**

I have added a new `If` to check the select cell isn't merged first, and only a single cell is selected.

Comment: i only want this to take affect for rows 17 onwards yes. With this code it keeps coming up with a type mismatch error when i click on cells in other places in the workbook.

Comment: Does this happen when you click on a merged cell?

Comment: thanks tried the edit, doesn't seem to perform the delete row or anything now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo Errormask '<-- don't see the need for this line

    With Target
        If .Column = 30 And .Row > 16 And .Value Like "Remove" Then
            .EntireRow.Delete
            .Offset(, 2).Select
        End If
    End With

Errormask: '<-- don't see the need for this line
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Exit Sub '<-- don't see the need for this line, anyway at the end of the Sub

End Sub
```